# php, delete if amount is less than 1 or 0

Tags: php, if-statement

Im trying to delete a record from my db when the amount is less than 1 or 0.

This is for a cart application

```
$aantal = $this->getCurrentAantal();
if ($aantal > 0 )
{
    $aantal--;
} 
else 
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: _Im trying to delete a record.._ Where is the relevant code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I advise you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article as it provides very useful information for newcomers on how to write questions. Quality questions help us provide you quality answers

Comment: not really sure about how to edit my question but heres more code
https://hastebin.com/utizuvazub.xml

Comment: _not really sure about how to edit my question..._ Click the "edit" button below your question